# Implement functions in link or pass $scope to function outside link

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

My questions is what is best practice + more efficient?
Implementing functions that use $scope inside the Link function, or implemet it outside and pass $scope to it?

```
angular.module('exampleModule', [])
    .directive('exampleDirective', ['$http',
        function ($http) {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope: {
                    ...
                },
                link: function ($scope, element, attr) {
                    /* Implement here? */
                    function myFunc(){
                        /* do some calc using $scope*/
                    }
                },
                templateUrl: "..." 
            }

            /**
            * Assistant Functions
            */
            /* Implement here? */
                function myFunc($scope){
                    /* do some calc using $scope*/
                }
        }]);
```

Comment: Imo implementing it outside just makes the code messier and harder to read - just put it inside the link function, that way anyone reading it understands what's going on

Comment: This question doesnt make sense at all. Its like "Which sort of mayonnaise do I need for a sandwich?".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can define the function at bottom, and just give the reference to that function, and that function will receive all the arguments when it will be
for ex.

```
angular.module('exampleModule', [])
    .directive('exampleDirective', ['$http',
        function ($http) {
            return {
                restrict: 'EA',
                scope: {
                    ...
                },
                link: myFunc, // just the reference to the function to be invoked
                templateUrl: "..." 
            }

            //link function
            function myFunc($scope, element, attr){
                 /* do some calc using $scope*/
                 $scope.someResult = calculateSomeResult($scope.someArg);
                 // use the sub function to perform calculation and give only required thing as argument, don't pass entire $scope
            }

            function calculateSomeResult(someArg) {
                return someArg * 2; //here perform any calculation or anything. and return the result
            }
        }]);
```

its not necessary that you have pass anonymous function always you can pass any function reference and when that function will be invoked it will be given the three argument so you can get that argument directly in your function no need to create extra layer of scope and function.

Comment: Hi Sam, the question isn't about the link function itself but about declaring other functions inside the link function or outside

Comment: you can declare any function outside or inside the link function, i think keeping it outside is good, and don't pass $scope to any other function, your function should be pure which only accepts argument and return result, which you use in your main function and add to scope if necessary so in that case you won't have to pass scope to any other function. for ex. i am updating answer.